# Node.js: Object translates to undefined in the response object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple function as defined below

```
function upload(response, postData) {
    console.log("Received: " + postData);
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    response.write("You've sent text: " + querystring.parse(postData).text);
    response.end();
}
```

When I log the data in to console, it shows properly but on writing into response object shows as "undefined". Why this happens? Is there any mistake in my code?

## Whole code

### route.js

```
function route(handle, pathname, response, postData) {
    console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
    if(typeof(handle[pathname]) === 'function') {
        console.log(postData);
        handle[pathname](response, postData);
    } else {
        console.log("no request handler found for " + pathname);
        response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("404 Not found");
        response.end();
    }
}

exports.route = route;
```

### requestHandler.js

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
var querystring = require("querystring");

function start(response, postData) {
    console.log("request handler 'start' was called");
    var body = '<html>' +
    '<head>' +
        '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; ' +
        'charset=UTF-8" />' +
    '</head>'+
    '<body>'+
        '<form action="/upload" method="post">'+
            '<textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>'+
            '<input type="submit" value="Submit text" />'+
        '</form>'+
    '</body>' + '</html>';

    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write(body);
    response.end();
}

function upload(response, postData) {
    console.log("Received: " + querystring.parse(postData).text);
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    response.write("You've sent text: " + querystring.parse(postData).text);
    response.end();
}

exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
```

### server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start(route,handle) {

    function onRequest(request,response) {
        var postData = "";
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        console.log("Request received for " + pathname + " received.");
        request.setEncoding("utf8");
        request.addListener("data", function(postDataChunk) {
            postData += postDataChunk;
            console.log("Received POST data chunk '" + postDataChunk + "'.");
            });
        request.addListener("end", function() {
            console.log(postData);
            route(handle, pathname, response, postData);
            });
        route(handle,pathname,response);
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server has started...");
}

exports.start = start;
```

Comment: Could you please post the code showing the function call and it's arguments?

Comment: First instinct would suggest there is not a item `text` in your POST data.

Comment: Can you add `console.log(querystring.parse(postData))` to your code - and show the results here?

Comment: console.log prints it well. you can see the whole code above. I have updated

Comment: @Jivings can you make it clear?

Comment: It looks like you will route every request twice, once with and once without `postData`.

Comment: @LinusGThiel please put this as answer, so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code executes twice with and without `postData`. Thanks Linus G Theil. I should be better clear about the code before posting.

Comment: To add a little more detail,this is fixed by removing the 2nd route request from server.js: ``route(handle,pathname,response);`` (this is already handled by the "end" event). [link - gist](https://gist.github.com/NickTomlin/4757283)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a typo - use

```
querystring.parse(postData).undefinedtext
```

for your upload function in requestHandler.js

I'm working through the same tutorial and got stuck here too.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously kinda late, but I had the same exact error as you, but I was not executing route twice. My mistake was that my postData variable was undefined and as a result it was giving

```
undefinedtext=sometext+querttest
```

This problem is easily fixed my initializing your postData = "". Hope this a helps any future visitor that gets stuck here.